# Is the Post Office Metric applicable in $\Bbb{R}^n$ for all $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I was required to provide a metric space $(X,d)$ with $x,y\in X$ and $0<r<R$ such that $B_R(x)\subsetneq B_r(y)$. After a lot of thinking and reading, I came by a metric function called the "Post Office Metric", always attributed to $\Bbb{R}^2$, in particular when giving examples for a metric space such as the above. I constructed a metric function (defined on $\Bbb{R}$) of the same concept as follows: $d(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
|x|+|y|,  & \text{if } x\ne y \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$, 
and to what I checked it seems like a legitimate metric function. Then I looked for it and came by nothing like that, and I begin to feel like I am doing something wrong. I would appreciate your thought on the matter.

Comment: In a way that concerns the integrity and understanding of the question, or a way that concern the language correctness? Because I am not native...

Comment: It's about the mathematics - not about language. Two things confuse me: 1) You quantify over $x,y$ but only use $x$. 2) It seems to me that the role of $r$ and $R$ are reversed.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention. The roles of $r$ and $R$, however, are not reversed. If they were, there wouldn't be a challenge in coming up with an example, if I assess correctly...

Comment: you probably want to use the *norm* of $x$ and $y$ rather than $|\cdot|$ which is usually reserved for the *absolute value* (of a number and not a vector).

Comment: I am quite confused; isn't the standard norm in $\Bbb{R}$ outputs the same values as Absolute Value Function? If so, if defined a metric function such that as long as it meets the criteria, I don't get why a norm is necessary. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $|x|$ (absolute value of $x$) does not make sense.

Comment: I agree with that, but I was initially looking at the real axis. Is it unequivocally unorthodox?

Comment: It just occurred to me that I've been been remiss in mentioning I was focusing on $\Bbb{R}$. Sorry for misleading you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest route would be to take $X$ to be a finite graph and let $d(x,y)$ be length of the shortest path between vertices $x,y$. So for instance, you might take $X$ to be the graph

> a----b----c----d----e

Note that $B_r(c)=X$ for any $r>2$. On the other hand, $B_R(e) \neq X$ when $R<4$.

**Added:** In fact, come to think of it, you can also achieve this with the interval $X=[0,1]$ in the ordinary absolute value metric. 
$$B_{0.8}(0) \subsetneq B_{0.6}(0.5)$$

Answer (score 2):

The idea is fundamentally similar to Mike F's answer, but perhaps simpler or at least more common in analysis.

Consider $X=[0,1]$ with the induced Euclidian metric. Let $x=0$; then $B_R(x)=[0,x)$. Take say, $R=1/2$.

Then take, say, $y= 1/3$ and $r=2/5$, we have that $B_r(y)=[0,11/15)\simeq [0,0.73)$.

Comment: +1, yeah I came to the same realization and edited it in.

Comment: @MikeF Oops, my answer had the r's mixed up. Yours is cleaner, and had the right idea from the get go anyway.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Have fun with the standard interval $[0, 1]$! I think that's what the other answer did. (saw the picture of the graph answer and that idea popped up at the same time the third answer came)

What about something like $d(x, y)=||x||/2+||y||$? Should be pretty easy to come up with the values of $x, y$ and $0<r<R$...assuming you meant for all your parameters to be existential.

Comment: That is not a metric: $d(x,y) \neq d(y,x)$.

Comment: darn! Oh well. Shouldn't be too hard to come up with something.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt. Do you have any insights on what I was attempting ?